# NASM INTEGER INPUT AND PRINTING INTEGER AFTER MANIPULATION

Tags: nasm

I am new to nasm, and i am trying to do the following in nasm i am using mac osx. Regardless of that fact just guide me to how to read integer from console

```
.data
_num word 0
_sum    word 0
_msg1   byte "Enter a number: ", 0
_msg2   byte "The sum is: ", 0

.code
main proc

mov edx, offset _msg1
call writestring
call readint
mov [_num], eax
call writestring
call readint

add eax, [_num]
mov [_sum], eax

call writestring
call readint

sub [_sum], eax
mov eax, [_sum]

call writeint

exit

main endp
end main
```

Comment: You have to read the string that was input in the console, then parse it as a base-10 integer (though base-16 would be slightly easier to parse). Reading can be done by using system calls, while parsing has to be implemented manually.

Comment: How will i know what length of string to specify. Should i fix a buffer size, for example: push dword 8 push num push dword 1